# ZFS Not Recovering Space

Tags: debian, virtualization, zfs, proxmox

I've certainly made a few rookie mistakes when setting up my first ZFS from a 4 drive array (14tb platters), mainly forgetting to change the block size from default. However I am missing space in my summary and I 'think' I know what is happening but trying to get clarification.

I have a container allocated at 300Gb using ~30Gb of space. I setup two containers at 5000Gb but destroyed them after realizing I configured them wrong.

My summary is now missing 10Tb of space but ZFS list does not show the space being used.

I did select to destroy the space while deleting but it seems that space is not being recovered. Is this just a matter of waiting for some garbage collection process or will this happen every time, and how do I prevent it?

I am going to just destroy the ZFS and rebuild it since it's a new machine and not much loss from what I've done so far since I mucked up the block size initially.

Just trying to make the correct changes going forward and can't find any directly relevant information online.

Thanks.

Photos:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/juabs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVB6D.png

Edit: typos

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please [take the tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) to learn how Server Fault works. Read [how to ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Comment: IE: Please post some `zfs` commands related to the space usage. Prefer text to images (-;

Comment: @freezed I think I am just a noob and didn't take the time to realize the loss was coming from zraid. It would make sense that some loss would come from this, but I didn't think about that as a possibility at the time. :P thanks for responding